# SMO Transfer Class to transfer table with none default schema

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, smo

In SSIS I am using the code from the blog ..
[Blog to use SMO Transfer class](http://www.sqltechnet.com/2012/08/ssis-transfer-sql-server-object-using.html)

I only want to transfer two tables, each with different schema ..

`dbo.table1`

`ctl.table2`

The table `dbo.table1` gets transferred.

I get an error with `ctl.table2`.

The error is `Value cannot be Null`.

I checked Transfer.Options properties but not really finding anything that will help.

Also I tried by setting `Transfer.CopyAllSchemas = True` but this does not help either.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Found the Method in Transfer Class to use to transfer Object with `ctl` schema instead of `dbo`.

For specific schema we need to use ..

```
xfr.ObjectList.Add(db.Tables("Table2", "Ctl"))
```

This will transfer `ctl.Table2.